# How to determine cluster rotation around z-axis?

Tags: cluster-computing, ros, point-cloud-library

I have a `<PointXYZ>` cloud that needs to be clustered.
I've used `pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction` to extract the clusters,
Also, I've used `pcl::computeCentroid(*(cluster),centroid)` to get the centroid x,y,z values.
I am asking if there is a function like computeCentroid in pcl that can compute the rotation around the z-axis. If it is not implemented, may I know how to manually calculate it from the cluster points? ps: I know that manual calculation may slow the overall performance since I am not doing any optimizations.
Thanks.

Comment: What does "orientation around z axis" mean?

Comment: Rotation I mean around the z-axis

Comment: Do you mean the angle between the **(a)** vector from centroid to origin (0,0,0) projected on the XY plane and the **(b)** X axis?